# JavaScript. Dropdown menu - double color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, dropdown

I've a menu:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/39px2wga/1/
```

I want to achieve effect:
"If you click on Page1 in submenu in Menu1 -> you go to Page1 and at Page1 - the Menu1 and Page1 will change the colours - to show users where they are.

I can't use active class in css, beacuse i must do it in php module, and i think it must be in js.

I have the js code:

```
 $(function() {
  $("#menu li a").each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location) {
      $(this).css("color", "#ff851d");
    };
  });
});
```

It works, but only change the color of active link, but i want changing colour in active link and his parent (active link and menu where the link is)

Please help

Comment: just use this.parentNode or this.parent()

Answer (score 0):

This is working: https://jsfiddle.net/39px2wga/2/

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.style.color = "#ff851d";
```

-> I changed the if clause to work with jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks so much! But I have a one problem, beacuse I changed the idea ;-) I want to add the active link highlight color too. It is possible? please Help

//highlights for parents. So.. 1) Change color - Parents and child. 2) Highlights only for parents even if you click on child

Comment: If I understand correctly, just add a class to the parent element with a mousedown eventListener on the child elements. The class itselft contains the highlight color. See: [https://jsfiddle.net/39px2wga/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/39px2wga/4/)